# Pass value to injected EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, ejb, cdi

I have an EJB application that consists of two beans, `ServiceEJB` (web tier) and `BusinessEJB` (business tier), where `BusinessEJB`is injected in `ServiceEJB`.

`ServiceEJB`receives HTTP requests from the browser, calls a method in `BusinessEJB`, gets the result, and sends the HTTP response.

Also, `ServiceEJB` has access to the `HttpSession` object, where the `userId` of the user that logged in is stored. `BusinessEJB`does NOT have access to the `HttpSession` object.

The application needs to log messages (using sl4j/logback, for example). It could log the message in `ServiceEJB`or `BusinessEJB` methods, and when it logs a message, it has to include the `userId` of the session in the log entry.

Since `BusinessEJB` doesn't have the `userId`, it needs to get it from `ServiceEJB`. The question is what is the best way to achieve that. What I DON'T want to do is to add a `userId` field to each method in `BusinessEJB` as a parameter, as there are many `ServiceEJB`s and `BusinessEJB`s in the application (and other beans called by `BusinessEJB` that also generate log entries), and I don't want to pollute the application with the `userId` field. Instead, I could have a `userId` field at the EJB level, but how to populate them? Is there a way to achieve this with annotations? Any suggestions will be welcome.

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Stateless
public class ServiceEJB {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Inject
    private BusinessEJB bean;

    private String userId;

    @Path("someurl")
    public Response someMethod1() {
       final HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
       // get the userId from the session

       String s = bean.someMethod2();

       // return Response
    }
}

@Stateless
public class BusinessEJB {

  private String userId;

  public String someMethod2() {
     // ....  log an entry with userId
     return "something";
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few pointers/comments:

1. If you integrate with application server security, then the user name is available at any component. EJBs can get it by calling `getCallerPrincipal()` on the injected variant of the `EJBContext`, here the `javax.ejb.SessionContext`:

   ```
   @Resource
   private SessionContext sessionCtx;
   ```

   Servlets can retrieve the principal from the `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`. JAX-RS components (the `ServiceEJB`) can retrieve it from the `javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal()`.

   Is there any reason why you are NOT integrating with the application server security?
2. If you have a good reason NOT to integrate with application server security, I would propose a variation of the solution from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399541/2764255). The variation is to set the user data from a filter applied to all resources (either servlet filter or JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter`), so that you do not have to worry about setting it in multiple places.
3. If you ONLY NEED THE USER ID FOR LOGGING, I'd suggest you take a look at the concept of Mapped Diagnostic Contexts (MDC) in slf4j. With it you can set the user id early at the beginning of the request and make it available to all logging statements thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using MDC, the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a request scoped CDI bean i.e. `UserContext`.

Inject it into both EJBs.

In `ServiceEJB` set user's id and in `BusinessEJB` read it.